# (not-duplicate)Github actions "enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file."

Tags: github, github-actions, npm-install, package.json, npm-start

my project structure is like this:

```
flight_list
|
|
app
|
|--backend
|
|--frontend
```

I have gone through other stackoverflow threads about this problem. I understood the root cause of the problem. The problem is occurring because npm could not find the package.json but, when I tried to change directory I was not able to which results in "enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file."

[github actions log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8AZH.png)

I got the idea of changing directory from these github issues.
https://github.com/Azure/actions/issues/47

I tried changing directory in the workflow file but it didn't workout i used pwd command to check the current directory location it is showing up same.

[actions log after changing to directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiEHT.png)

**Note:**
this is my workflow file

```
name: on_pr_update

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [ opened, synchronize, reopened ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x, 16.x, 18.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
        cache-dependency-path: ./app/back-end/package-lock.json 
    - run: pwd
    - run: cd app/back-end/
    - run: pwd
    - run: npm install
    - run: npm run build --if-present
    - run: npm test
    - run: npm lint
```